# How to display json web response in angular template?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to display some JSON data that comes as HTTP web response, but it's not working.

Below is my http request:

```
nodes: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
    // Make the HTTP request:
    this.http.get('/assets/TEST.json').subscribe(data => {
        // Read the result field from the JSON response.
        this.nodes=data;
    });
}
```

And this is the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let node of nodes">
    <p>{{node.description}}</p>
</div>
```

This is my json data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "root1",
    "link": "/login"
}
```

This the error I get in console:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'root1' where root1 is a component different from the one where the request is made.

Comment: did u tried `this.nodes = data.json()` ?

Comment: @Med_Ali_Rachid yes , I tried it, but it doesn't work

Comment: try to log `data` => `console.log(data)` , it shows the json ? @eli

Comment: @Med_Ali_Rachid yes, I ge the json in console

Comment: what's the nature of the JSON is it an array, an object.. ? can u edit the post and show a screenshot of ur json

Comment: @Med_Ali_Rachid I updated the question

Comment: u can't use the *ngFor to fetch an object .. usually we use it with arrays , here u can show your object directly like that : `<p>{{nodes.id}}</p>`

Comment: @Med_Ali_Rachid If I do that , I get : `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: since we are getting data in an asynchrounous way using subscribing ,the nodes is `undefined` at beginning , i think the solution is simply like that : `<p>{{nodes?.id}}</p>` (we added ? to test if nodes is not `undefined` )

Comment: @Med_Ali_Rachid I did that and I don't get any errors , but the data is not displaying

Comment: so weird ! what if u do just this `<p>{{nodes}}</p>` ? 
can you create a simple demo in plunker ?

Comment: @Med_Ali_Rachid your solution is fine, I had incorrectly written `{{nodes.description}}` instead of `{{node.name}}` at the template and that's why nothing was being displayed

Comment: should i posted as an answer for ur question now ? (`<p>{{nodes?.id}}</p>` that worked fine , is it ? )

Comment: @Med_Ali_Rachid it works fine even without the `?`

Comment: Okey , I posted the answer in which i explain the cause of your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our investigations in comments the solution :

- `*ngFor` shouldn't be used there since his JSON is an object not an array

so the solution is simply :

```
<p> id : {{nodes.id}}</p>
<p> name : {{nodes.name}}</p>
<p> link : {{nodes.link}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your JSON is an object, not an array. Therefore, you can't use `ngFor`. As your object doesn't have a `description` property (but a `name`), you may display the name (make sure that nodes has been set) using this template:

```
<p *ngIf="nodes">{{ nodes.name }}</p>
```

Comment: What if I had two or more JSON objects ?

Comment: If it had (ie, your file contains an array), then you could use `ngFor`.